# When performing post via ajax, Bad Request is returned instead of the JSON result

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, jqxhr, asp.net-mvc-5.1

## Javascript

```
jqXHR = $.ajax({ url: $frm.attr("action"), type: "POST", dataType: "json", cache: false,
  headers: headers, contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8", data: ko.mapping.toJSON(data, map),
  beforeSend: function(x) {
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
      return x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  }
});

jqXHR.fail(function(xhr, err, msg) {  /* xhr.responseText  NEED TO BE JSON!!! */ });
```

## In Chrome

**Headers**

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source {Id:0}
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:54
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 27 Feb 2014 14:01:59 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.1
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**Response**

> [{"Name":"Nome","ErrorMessage":"campo obrigatório."}]

**Works in chrome!**

---

## In IE8

**Headers (Request)**

```
POST /Motivos/Salvar HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pt-br
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Content-Length: 10
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Headers (Response)**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 13:51:46 GMT
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

**NOT WORK!!**

## Asp.net MVC

### Filter

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            var ex = filterContext.Exception.GetBaseException();
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    ex.Message,
                    ex.GetType().Name
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

**Apply on GlobalFilterCollection**

### Controller

```
[ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken, HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult Salvar(TViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TEntity model;
        if (default(TKey).Equals(viewModel.Id))
        {
            model = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(viewModel);
            AdicionarEntidade(model, viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            model = Repositorio.Get(viewModel.Id);
            Mapper.Map(viewModel, model, typeof(TViewModel), typeof(TEntity));
            SalvarEntidade(model, viewModel);
        }

        return SalvarResult(model);
    }

    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return Json(ModelState.ToJson(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### Extenssion

```
public static object ToJson(this ModelStateDictionary dic, params string[] othersMessages)
{
    var states = (from e in dic where e.Value.Errors.Count > 0
                  select new { Name = e.Key, e.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage }).ToList();

    if (othersMessages != null)
        foreach (var message in othersMessages)
            states.Add(new { Name = "", ErrorMessage = message });

    return states;
}
```

## Questions

- Why not have the xhr.resposeText object?
- How to retrieve JSON in the same way that I recover in Chrome?

I need the JSON to populate the form!

## Notes: 03/11/2014

When I add `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` in my controler, it works! 
responseText returns the json. 
Why?

Comment: If you set a different content-type in [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it'd be wise to set processData to false. Also, why are you [overriding mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType()) in beforeSend?  You have control over the return type on the server.

Comment: can you show what's the value in data: ko.mapping.toJSON(data, map) on both IE and chrome?

Comment: @KerryLiu Even setting `processData: false`, the error occurs.    
* About `beforeSend`, it was just a test. Even removed this event this error still occurs!

Comment: @LeeGary The data: **In IE** `"{"Id":"0"}"` ,  **In Chrome** `"{"Id":"0"}"`

Comment: Is it just me, or are your Chrome (response?) headers showing status code `400 Bad Request` as well?

Comment: @BrianNorth Is correct. ha that a required field is not filled, the status is correct in Chrome. responseText is is wrong in IE

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Think this is an issue with IIS trying to use custom error response rather sending the error message that the controller is generating.

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Or

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029197/1304559

Check out this blog post http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors

Since response code is set to 400, IIS replaces your content with its custom error page content

Answer (score 2):

The issue I am seeing is that your trying to set the encoding of the JSON to UTF-8. Normally it works just fine, however, on IIS, it has a custom error to report that the UTF-8 is not necessary.

Few other things to note. You are doing a POST, so the server will be expecting a json file. If provided none, it will not know what to do.

Comment: 1. About UTF-8 does not make sense, because it works in Chrome. I've tried removing the UTF-8 and the error still occurs!

Comment: 2. I am sending JSON to the server!

Comment: well what is the json that you are sending? You only show the response json, response is what the server sends the client. ALso, you can only send one json file at a time. So if you have multiple forms being submited at once, it needs to be packed as one json file.

Answer (score 2):

Your response comes back with `Content-Type: text/html` http header, but it should be `application/json`. This is not an issue in Chrome (and you don't get [mismatch warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3467404/1081234) in the console) because you're relying on [`overrideMimeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType%28%29)... which, you guessed it, is not IE-friendly. In fact, the following is never executed on older versions of IE:

```
if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
  return x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
}
```

Your solution could be to make sure the content is served with correct content type. If you're familiar with tampering tools like [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/), you could add the correct header on-the-fly and see if that fixes the problem. I would probably avoid inlining methods like [`AddHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and see if there is a way this can be fixed at a higher - routing, perhaps - level.

Answer (score 1):

I have filled in a fail test that should help.

```
$.post($frm.attr("action"), ko.mapping.toJSON(data, map))
.done(function (dataVal) {
    //process dataVal
    var mystruct = GenerateCache($.parseJSON(dataVal));
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    if (jqxhr.responseText.indexOf("YourMoniker") != -1) {
        parseData($.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText));
    } else {
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
    }
});


function GenerateCache(data) {
    var obj = function () { };
    obj.prototype = data;
    return new obj();
}
```

Specifically look at the error handling in the `.fail` section.

Comment: I use `$.ajax` because I set headers. how to set headers with `$.post`?

Comment: I see.  That is probably the only and best way if you are going to try to set your own headers.

Comment: What is it in your headers that you need specifically?

Comment: You can send the dataType like `$.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )`. You can also add data to the query string in the url like: `/getData.aspx?param1=test&param2=54...`.  And this still let's you send the data.

Comment: Seeing as the `$.ajax` method sends the exact same request with `method: 'POST'` as `$.post` does, and the sent/received headers in the OP do show that IE is sending it as a `POST` request, changing from the one method to the other will get the *exact* same results

Comment: But it reduces the amount of extra work if you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your controller, that's working fine. You're missing a required field: both IE and Chrome are returning status code `400 Bad Request` - but only Chrome is properly processing the `responseText` and giving you `[{"Name":"Nome","ErrorMessage":"campo obrigatório."}]` meaning you have a missing form field.

Although I've searched all over and haven't found any reference to specific IE bugs in processing `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` with non-200 status codes, it looks like IE is replacing your response body with its own:

```
Headers (Response)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

Indicates that the "content" as it treats it is the "Bad Request" status text, not the proper json response (which Chrome reads as content-length 54, for instance). This might mean IE is discarding your response body (I doubt it, that'd be bloody incredible) or it just isn't be processed "properly." Try dumping the rest of your `jqXHR` object and the arguments for your `fail` handler to see if you can find it in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

IE (all versions, including IE11) will put "Bad Request" in the status text and ignore the JSON you put in as the message.

In order to use the xhr.responseText in IE on error, you need to throw an exception instead of returning a Json or JsonResult with `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;`

So... before:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Json(new { Message = "There is already a distribution set which covers part or all of this period" });
```

This works in Chrome, FF and any sane browser, really.
After:

```
throw new Exception("You have posted invalid datas.");
```

As an unhandled exception, it will be passed to the browser as a response, this will work in Chrome, FF and even in IE. It is not graceful, same as all unhandled exceptions (or just exceptions, for that matter), but it will do the job of letting you receive an appropriate response.