# Debugging 400 Bad Request response

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, bad-request

In my MVC application, when a POST request is sent to the server (via jQuery) and a validation error occurs, a 400 Bad Request is returned, as intended:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Thu, 26 Feb 2015 08:35:50 GMT
Content-Length: 174

{"ReturnValue":null,"Results":[{"Message":"The xyz field is required.","ErrorNumber":123,"Severity":1}]}
```

This works as intended on my local machine. However when I deploy the application to the server, the response for the exact same request looks different:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Thu, 26 Feb 2015 08:37:01 GMT
Content-Length: 24

Invalid Request
```

Note that the content type is `text/html`, and the response body doesn't contain JSON anymore.

What could be the cause of this? I would appreciate a pointer where to start debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further searching and reading I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071211/when-performing-post-via-ajax-bad-request-is-returned-instead-of-the-json-resul) which also refers to the helpful article [IIS 7 Error Pages taking over 500 Errors](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors)

the problem was IIS taking over 400 Bad Request errors and replacing my custom JSON response with IIS error content. This behavior can be disabled using the `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` setting:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = 400;
```