# IIS Custom Errors - Returning JSON Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a very strange situation with my asp.net MVC application.

In one of my controllers has the following code in for a request that usually returns a JSON of an object if there is an error:

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();
string error = "I want to show this error";
errors.Add(error);
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors, Formatting.Indented);
```

Also in my web config file I have the following rules for IIS errors (note: there's no rule for 500 error!):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"       defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404" />
  <remove statusCode="403" />
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404" />
</httpErrors>
```

When I have that in my web.config file whenever there is an issue I simply receive the default Error - 500 page as the response:

```
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric…↵ </fieldset> ↵</div> ↵</div> ↵</body> ↵</html> ↵", status: 500
```

If on my local machine I comment out the error rules in web.config then I start receiving the message I want and not the HTML for the 500 error page. However, no matter what I do when this is released on a server I always get returned the 500 error page html.

Does anyone know of an easy way round this or is there another way of sending back the specific error to the view?

Comment: Can you show your whole `<httpErrors>` section?

Comment: Error 500 normally means internal server error. Pretty much I would take a guess that your code is not executing properly when in the server. Would you have any log or full display of the error being generated?

Comment: Error 500 is just the error I have selected to return the response as, I could put anything there, that isn't the issue here, the issue is that I receive the HTML of the default error 500 page and not the error string I would like back.

Comment: The code that you showed does not explain logic completely. It's better to show us try-catch block and the place where you write data to response.

Comment: I can put it but you honestly won't get anything else from the try catch, it is 100% hitting that code as it should be and I need to know how to get the response to be string error = "I want to show this error"; instead of the HTML of the default 500 error page.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782635/asp-net-mvc-showing-error-page-on-when-sending-responses-with-status-500